# Skip lines with matching pattern and delete lines with condition matched

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have file with following format :

```
Q
L
A D
1 10
2 21
3 22
4 5
5 9
```

I need to skip lines which starts with 'Q' or 'L' and delete lines where second column has value greater than 10 and save the entire thing in new file. Example output files :

```
Output file 1
    Q
    L
    A D
    1 10
    4 5
    5 9 

Output file 2
1
4
5
```

Code :

```
while read -r line; if [[ $line == "A" ]] ||[[ $line == "Q" ]]||[[ $line == "L" ]] ; then 
awk '$2 < "11" { print $0 }' test.txt
awk '$2 < "11" { print $1 }' test1.txt
done < input.file
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want, please describe what's in output file 1 and output file 2 separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to filter for lines that start with letters A or L or Q plus a condition. `awk` is a good fit for something like this:

```
awk '($0 ~ /^[AQL]/ || $2 < 11) { print $0 }' < input.file > output.file1
awk '($0 ~ /^[^AQL]/ && $2 < 11) { print $1 }' < input.file > output.file2
```

Comment: @Thor, thanks, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with below command and it worked fine

command

```
awk '$1 !~ "Q|L" && $2 <11{print $1}' filename
```

output

```
awk '$1 !~ "Q|L" && $2 <11{print $1}' filename
1
4
5
```